# Salesforce LiveAgent Implementation on external website with failover to an alternate button

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud

[How to setup pre-chat form in HTML to embed in customer website?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21547/how-to-setup-pre-chat-form-in-html-to-embed-in-customer-website/44006#44006): My questions is in reference to this post/response.

I have a requirement which is similar in nature in terms of external website chat integrated with Salesforce LiveAgent with a difference that a pre-chat form needs to be filled out and the routing of the chat needs to be determined by the country selected in pre-chat form.

There are 7 buttons configured, each button associated with a country. In addition, the fail-over needs to be implemented where, if a button/agent is offline then a chat needs to be directed to a generic button/skill group.

I have started implementing with VF page and sites, however, half way through realize that it may not fit the requirement. Please share your thoughts and how should i be approaching the solution for this requirement.