# Implementing a pre-chat form with Live Agent and Community Builder

Tags: liveagent, community-builder, pre-chat, napili

Is there any documentation (or any standard way) to create a pre-chat form for Live Agent if we are using the Napili template in Community Builder?

I was able to get the pre-chat button working thanks to some of the helpful articles here on creating lightning components.

From the looks of it, the only options for a pre-join form in the setup area are visualforce pages, which I don't believe are easily included within site templates.  There appears to be a workaround using iframes, but Salesforce announced that's going to go away after Winter '16.

Could this possibly be implemented using a lightning component?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21547/how-to-setup-pre-chat-form-in-html-to-embed-in-customer-website/21567#21567