# Live agent button from external website

Tags: visualforce, liveagent

I need to make a live chat button for a customer that will be on their site externally from salesforce. They requested pre/post chat pages. I did some investigating and found this article which is great [How to setup pre-chat form in HTML to embed in customer website?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21547/how-to-setup-pre-chat-form-in-html-to-embed-in-customer-website).

But I still have a few more questions.

I would like to be able to write these pages in visual force so I do not need to touch the customers code base on their website. I see that you can select a visual force page in the live agent button configuration. [image]

My question is will users need to be logged into salesforce to see visual force pages?

Users will not be logged in since they will be accessing live chat from an external website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your users will not need to log in. You can surface this functionality without requiring authentication by adding the `Visualforce Page(s)` in question to a **[`Force.com Site`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites)** (emphasis added):

> Force.com Sites lets you create public web applications and web sites that run natively on Force.com - under your own domain. Force.com Sites lets you easily extend the reach of your existing applications to new, external audiences, and **your site visitors don't need to authenticate to view your pages**. In fact, if you're already using Visualforce to create your user interfaces, it's a simple matter of bundling them into a Force.com Site to create a public web application.